# Django Urls regex to suport old php pages

Tags: python, regex, django, python-2.7, django-urls

I'm migrating a system from PHP to Python/Django.

From the old website I shuld keep the most visited urls for a while, but I'm trying and I did'nt find a way.

The old format is:

```
detalhes.php?tipo=residuo&residuo_id=320
```

I've tried all this urls below but I keep getting 404:

```
url(r'^detalhes(?P<antigo>[\w]+)$','core.views.anuncio_antigo',name='anuncio-antigo'),
url(r'^detalhes(?P<antigo>[\w_-]+)$','core.views.anuncio_antigo',name='anuncio-antigo'),
url(r'^detalhes\.php\?tipo\=residuo\&residuo_id\=(?P<antigo>[\w_-]+)$','core.views.anuncio_antigo',name='anuncio-antigo'),
url(r'^(?P<antigo>[\w_-]+)$','core.views.anuncio_antigo',name='anuncio-antigo'),
```

And I always receive this:

```
[22/Apr/2013 20:08:58] "GET /detalhes.php?tipo=residuo&residuo_id=58 HTTP/1.1" 404 7099
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do what I was trying to do is don't handle the querystring with the URL dispatcher. Instead of, I've done this:

```
url(r'^detalhes\.php/$', 'core.views.anuncio_antigo',name='anuncio-antigo'),
```

Any of those php files now will call my `anuncio_antigo` view. Then in view I handled the querystring using `request.GET`, like this:

```
tipo = request.GET.get('tipo')
residuo_id = request.GET.get('residuo_id')
```

I think it's not possible to have a question mark in a url.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me in the same situation was to configure the web server to route requests on different engines. Config we used with nginx was something like this:

```
location ~ ^/(django\/adm|someurl|)/.*$ {
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/path/to/uwsgi.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
    }

location ~ ^/(_.*\.php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass   php_fastcgi;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/path/to/index/php/$1;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/path/to/index/php/$1;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: thanks singer, but I don't want to use the php anymore, I have new models and views to deal with the old urls.

Comment: What stops you to use your web server for this task? simple apache rewrite rule or nginx location will do the job. It is webserver responsibility to manage this kind of problems, there must be a reason to handle this urls with framework.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to do this using django, in despite of the php extension, I have new models and views to handle the old pages.